# Wordpress Page Builder is mixing up with theme - why?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am new to Wordpress but not HTML and CSS. I installed a theme and then got the Page Builder Plugin.

When I use the page builder it seems to want to create a lovely crips full width site but it goes over the the top of some of the theme style/content.

It's mixed up.

How do I get page builder to be the only source for the overall design.

I considered using CSS to hide some elements of the theme and have managed to hide the side bar - is this the best practice?

Please see the linkhttp://www.daneliandesigns.co.uk/wordpress/

If it is a case of just using CSS to hide certain elements then great! But I am thinking there is a simpler way as it is in Wordpress.

Comment: Why don't you just edit theme style directly instead of using plugins? You can also create page templates by creating template files... you can also apply your custom styles in wordpress posts/pages with the code editor

Comment: Great idea. I still want to be able to use Page Builder though - I have seen it done in YouTube videos and it is not affecting the theme they use at all.

Comment: Of course they would show a theme that does not conflict with their plugin! If you insist on using it then you'd have to modify the CSS to prevent any mix up. Use the dev inspector to work out the kinks and change the CSS accordingly, there's no other way and you might end up doing drastic changes to the theme stylesheet.

Comment: Ok thanks! I guess you still need to know your CSS to get things done in Wordpress.